# DocuSign: "This authentication mode is not supported: NONE" when trying to finish a signed document

Tags: docusignapi

I have a problem with a DocuSign flow on staging environment. After signing a document and clicking on continue button I have an error:

*This authentication mode is not supported: NONE*

It's a little bit strange because on production I have the same code and everything is working fine. I'm using different docusign account but both accounts (demo and production) have same settings.

Besides this, there are also a small differences in docusign flow buttons ([staging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh1Xl.png) vs [production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fbMe.png)).

After signing the document, instead of "continue" button there is a "finish" button.

Staging used to work fine and looks like production for a long time but few days ago that changed. Do you know why there are differences between these two environments and how to fix staging?

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote please?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is mentioned in this article with the solution, please have a look
https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/000043153?language=en_US

As discussed in the support article, Standards Based Signing often requires signer authentication. Your signing request did not included a needed authentication step, that's an error.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> Do you know why there are differences between these two environments

Yes, DocuSign works to improve its products. The demo ("staging") environment is used as a final test for new releases before they're installed on the production systems.

The UX changes you noticed will soon be implemented on the production systems too. In some cases, UX changes are only made for selected account plans (eg web purchased accounts vs enterprise accounts).